# Use Mybatis get sequence not follow squences

Tags: java, spring-mybatis

I use Mybatis get postgreDB sequences

The **import_order_seq** set

> "Increment By" 1
>
> "Max value" 9999
>
> "Min valu" 1
>
> "Cache Value" 20

the Mybatis xml

```
<select id="getSequence" resultType = "java.lang.String">
   select import_order_seq.nextval from dual 
</select>
```

The java code

```
String x = xxxx.getSequence()
```

The problem is when I execute the java code x is 21 ,41,61,81.....,
not 1,2,3,4....
How can I let x is 1,2,3,4....??

Comment: Set the useCache=true for select statement. I am not sure how you are managing the database connection. Hope it is managed by Spring with connection pooling.

Comment: @Brian you can identify easily it is taking cache value....each time +20 to previous value.